# Creating a has_many association in a hidden-field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say User has_many Things.  In a User form, I'd like a hidden_field that lets me create a relationship between this new User and a pre-existing Thing, say of id 8.  What's wrong with the following code snippet?  I think I'm just forgetting some syntax here.

```
<% f.hidden_field 'things[]', :value => 8 %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% f.hidden_field 'thing_id[]', :value => 8 %>
```

Answer (score 10):

For the posterity... If you have multiple values for 'things' that needs to be sent to the server in array, here is how to make it work:

```
<% user.things.each do |thing| %>
    <% f.hidden_field 'thing_ids][', :value => thing.id %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the reverse brackets with things_ids][. If brackets are not reversed server gets `"thing_ids"=>[nil, nil]`, supposing user had 2 things. With reversed brackets you will get correct thing ids in param thing_ids array.

Comment: thanks for this.  This worked for me.  The solution by @ghoppe didn't